# Enable and disable whitespace key in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day,

I would like to enable/disable whitespace key, such that the string does not allow whitespace key to be pressed at the beginning and end of a string, but in between should be accepted.

Please see the following string pattern, such that X represents deny of whitespace from being entered.

> XyyyyyX

In the following code, I have disabled whitespace key by default, such that the first letter will not be whitespace letter.

Followed by enabling whitespace key as soon as my first and the last letters are not whitespace letter.
Both "else if" executions are failed to enable whitespace key.

Appreciate your time in reviewing this question, thank you.

```
$("#input").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32)
        return false;
    else if(this.value.charAt(0) != ' ')
        return true;
    else if(this.value.charAt(this.value.length - 1) != ' ')
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Instead of disable whitespace key, i think you should trim whitespace from user provided string.

Answer (score 1):

`keydown()` fires before the key is inserted into the input field, so your event handler function will run too soon. Also, you have no way of knowing which position the character is being typed in; the user might be typing in the beginning, middle, or end of the string. And last but not least, there are other ways for the value in the input field to be changed that don't involve the `keydown` or `keyup` events.

One way to solve your problem that bypasses Javascript (and jQuery) entirely is to use a [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp):

```
<input id="input" pattern="^[^\s]+.*[^\s]+$">
```

But if you prefer to use jQuery:

```
$("#input").keyup(function (e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.trim()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a custom handler to prevent whitespace from being entered, you can just use [.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) method:

```js
$('#getVal').click(function(){
  console.log($('#input').val());
  console.log($('#input').val().trim());
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<input type="text" id="input" value="     AAAA    " />
<input type="button" id="getVal" value="Get value">
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want a string without any whitespaces around it, you can use `trim` function to remove whitespace at the begining and start of the string. you don't need to disable whitespace key for this case.

For eg.

```
$("#input").keydown(function (e) {
    let string = $(this).val();
    string = string.trim(); // this will remove whitespace around the string
    // now process string however you want
})
```

Comment: That just creates a local variable without any leading or trailing whitespace. If you want to update the input field accordingly, you need to add: `$(this).val( string )`.

Comment: Disabling a whitespace key is not a good user experience, what if user wants to write something like "John Snow", disabling whitespace key will not let user do that. there will be no "in between space". because after word "john" , you will disable whitespace key and user will hae to figure what the is going on to write word "snow".

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$("#input").keydown(function (e) {
    var inputControl = document.getElementById('input');
    var startPos = inputControl.selectionStart;
    var endPos = inputControl.selectionEnd;
    var end = inputControl.value.length;

if (e.keyCode == 32 && (startPos==0 || startPos==end))
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: Some explenation what you're doing here would help.

Comment: The code first captures the control and keyboard cursor's position (using inputControl.selectionStart) & length of the string in the control. It then compares, if space bar is pressed (e.keyCode == 32) && if the cursor is at the last position (startPos==end) of the string OR at the beginning (startPos==0) of the string in control. If it is true, it does not let user type anything by returning false. Otherwise, it allows normal typing based on keyboard keys.